# Callover showing overtop bootstrap select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I can't seem to suppress the data callout of the slide bar below the drop down menu when I mouse over the words in the dropdown and it is where the slider bar exists.

Please see image and jsfiddle as this is confusing to explain.

I am using bootstrap-select and bootstrap-slider.

https://jsfiddle.net/wolfpack06/u2z7tp0m/
**Click the "Screen Criteria" button to view the modal with issues.**

Thanks in advance[image: ![Issue][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5grX.png)

```
                <div class="container">
                    <form>

                        <!-- Symbols -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="symbols" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Symbols</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" multiple data-actions-box="true" id="symbols">
                                    <optgroup label="Index/ETF">
                                            <option>SPX</option>
                                            <option>IBB</option>    
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Stock">
                                            <option>NFLX</option>
                                            <option>TSLA</option>   
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;Not finding a symbol? <a href="#">Request it</a>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <!-- Spread Types -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Spread Types</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                        <input id="typebullput" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Bull Put Spreads
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                        <input id="typebullput" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Bear Call Spreads                                 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Expiration Distance -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="expirationdistance" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Expiration Distance</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <!-- double slider -->
                                <span id="expirationdistancelow" class="hidden">Low Distance</span>
                                <span id="expirationdistancehigh" class="hidden">High Distance</span>
                                <input id="expirationdistance" type="text"/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="expirationdistancelabel"><span id="expirationdistanceval">0,35</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="includeweeklyexpiration" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" disabled> Include weekly expirations
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Maximum Delta -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Maximum Delta</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="maximumdelta" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="0.25" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="0.08" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="maximumdeltalabel"><span id="maximumdeltaval">0.08</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="maximumdelta-enabled" type="checkbox"/  checked> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div>                          

                        <!-- Spread Width -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="spreadwidth" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Spread Width</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <!-- double slider -->
                                <span id="spreadwidthlow" class="hidden">Low Width</span>
                                <span id="spreadwidthhigh" class="hidden">High Width</span>
                                <input id="spreadwidth" type="text"/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="spreadwidthlabel"><span id="spreadwidthval">5,15</span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Minimum Distance -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Distance (%)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumdistance" type="text" data-slider-min="5" data-slider-max="25" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="12" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumdistancelabel"><span id="minimumdistanceval">12</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumdistance-enabled" type="checkbox"/  checked> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <!-- Minimum Premium -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Premium</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumpremium" type="text" data-slider-min="0.05" data-slider-max="1.0" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="0.25" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumpremiumlabel"><span id="minimumpremiumval">0.25</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumpremium-enabled" type="checkbox"/  checked> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <!-- Minimum Profit disabled -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Target ROM (%)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumprofit" type="text" data-slider-min="1.0" data-slider-max="10.0" data-slider-step="0.25" data-slider-value="2.5" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumprofitlabel"><span id="minimumprofitval">2.5</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumprofit-enabled" type="checkbox"/> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <!-- Minimum Leg Vol disabled -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Short/Long Leg Volume</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumlegvol" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="10" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumlegvollabel"><span id="minimumlegvolval">10</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumlegvol-enabled" type="checkbox"/> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Minimum Short Leg Vol disabled -->
<!--                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Short Leg Vol</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumshortlegvol" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="10" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumshortlegvollabel"><span id="minimumshortlegvolval">10</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumshortlegvol-enabled" type="checkbox"/> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div> -->

                        <!-- Minimum Long Leg Vol disabled -->
<!--                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Long Leg Vol</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumlonglegvol" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="10" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumlonglegvollabel"><span id="minimumlonglegvolval">10</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumlonglegvol-enabled" type="checkbox"/> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div> -->

                        <!-- Minimum Open Interest -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2">Minimum Open Interest</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumopeninterest" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="100" disable/>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span id="minimumopeninterestlabel"><span id="minimumopeninterestval">100</span></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="minimumopeninterest-enabled" type="checkbox"/  checked> Enabled
                            </div>
                        </div>  




                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltips have a `z-index` of 1070 so your dropdown needs anything higher than that, for example:

```
.dropdown-menu{ z-index: 1080; }
```

Comment: thank you so much! I wasn't sure what the dropdown menu was called out as in css